# extract value after the endpoint and assign it to a child function in Java Script using Express

Tags: javascript, express

I am just 2 days old in JS, so, asking a question that may sound a basic one.
I have a server running at `localhost:8000/api/namespace`.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Welcome to deletion task!!!');
});

app.get('/api/namespace/:namespaceName', function (req, res) {
    namespaceName = res.send(req.params);
    console.log(`${namespaceName}`);
});

var server = app.listen(8000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

The output of `` console.log(`${namespaceName}`); `` is `object obect`

On accessing URL as `http://localhost:8000/api/namespace/abcd`, it is giving the output as `{"namespaceName":"abcd"}`.

What I am trying to achieve is to get the value "abcd" into a variable and pass it into a child process as an argument(${namespaceName}) to a shell script.

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.execFile('./restart.sh', [`${namespaceName}`],
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    }
});
```

I am not able to achieve it.
Help, please.

Comment: It should probably be something like `const { namespaceName } = req.params;`.

Comment: Thanks @Andy. Probably, a little more explanation would help me to try it out.

Comment: `req.params` is an object containing the URL params. That's called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).